# iOS6 Cell Text BackgroundColor

Tags: text, ios6, tableview, cell, background-color

In my tableView cell, theres a backgroundcolor on my text, and i have no clue on how to remove it.. Can some one help me here ?

[image]

I've tried

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.opaque = NO;
```

but aint working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
```

and:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
```